# Python webserver says "connection reset"

Tags: python

Earlier today I made a very basic python webserver using the socket library. It's supposed to be able to return basic html pages, and that's it. The server seems to work fine until I send a request to it through the browser. Since I programmed the server to send progress messages to the terminal whenever it starts listening on a port or accepts a connection, I can tell that it's made the connection, but the browser displays a "connection reset" message every time I try to load it. Looking through the logs, I found it curious that my connection success message was displayed twice for every time I loaded the page. Is this why the browser keeps displaying "connection reset"? I'm not too familiar with socket and HTTP, so please bear with me.

Here's the server:

```
import socket

host = ''
port = 8080

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

sock.bind((host,port))
sock.listen(1)
print("Listening for connections on port" + ' ' + str(port))

while 1:
    sock_sock, sock_addr = sock.accept()
    print("Accepted connection on port" + ' '  + str(port))
    sock_file = sock_sock.send(open("main_app.py").read(), 0)

print("Closing socket...")
sock_file.close()
sock_sock.close()
```

Comment: how does you request look like, through the browser? Are you using also port 8080?

Comment: Well, it loads, and after a few seconds it displays the "connection reset" message. And yes, I am using port 8080.

Comment: Literally the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527603/python-webserver-connection-reset-every-time-i-send-request), except for a tiny bit less effort in question title, tags and formatting. Interesting ...

Comment: @shmee i admit it :;)

Comment: I did not downvote the other question. But there's a perfectly good reason to do so. It helps the automatic cleanup to kick in. We should not have multiple instances of the exact same question on the site.

Comment: I reposed the question because it's time-sensitive and the other one wasn't getting any answers or views.